# XOR Operator - How does it work?

Tags: c#, binary, bitwise-operators, xor

Can you please explain me in plain English what is the XOR (`^`) operator and what it does in the following code:

```
public int GetHashCode(Box bx)
{
    int hCode = bx.Height ^ bx.Length ^ bx.Width;
    return hCode.GetHashCode();
}
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or#Computer_science

Comment: Just google the Truth table related to it.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkacc7k1.aspx

Comment: it looks like bitwise XOR

Answer (score 15, accepted):

XOR stands for exclusive or. It ensures that either A or B is true but never both. In this case we're doing a bitwise operation so you can make a nice little graph of the outcomes, they are as follows;

```
0 ^ 1 = 1
1 ^ 1 = 0
1 ^ 0 = 1
0 ^ 0 = 0
```

Since you're applying it to integers the above outcomes are applied to each bit in the operands. So lets just say you have the values 1, 2, 3 for height, length, and width respectively.

You would first have

0001 ^ 0010 resulting in 0011 then that would be XOR'd into 3 so 0011 ^ 0011 which gives you 0000

EDIT: supplying the wiki link from the comments to supplement my explanation; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or#Computer_science

EDIT: Why does `0001 ^ 0010` result in `0011`?

So it's best to do this bit by bit. Think of the operator iterating over the two sets of bits and comparing pairs of them. So in this case lets work from right to left (least significant to most in this case).

```
1 ^ 0 = 1 // xxx1
0 ^ 1 = 1 // xx11
0 ^ 0 = 0 // x011
0 ^ 0 = 0 // 0011  - end of input
```

so piecing that back together you get `0011`. Basically, take each pair of inputs and reference the truth table for the outcome. The comment shows the output with `x` being a value that has not yet been calculated.

With regard to collisions, yes, in this case there are plenty of collision. If I said it would be unique that was a poor word choice. What I really mean is that if you have 2, 8, 4 as your values XOR'n them in that order will always produce the same value.

Comment: @Groostav too expand on that further, it's being done here because the result of `a ^ b ^ c` will always be the same for those values. Prior to getting the hash they're basically melding all the values into one so that the hash is unique to the values for a, b, and c.

Comment: What does "bitwise operation" means?

Comment: @YairNevet bitwise means it's operating on the binary values one by one. As you see in my example I chose the integer values 1, 2, and 3. 0001, 0010 and 0011 are their representations in binary. Bitwise operators operate on those values rather than the integer representation of those values. So like if we were working with ASCII (I don't know what character it is) some character has a value of 0001, that would be treated exactly the same as the integer 1 because their binary representation is the same.

Comment: @YairNevet you can check the wiki article for more information http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation I don't think my explanation was very clear... But basically all types are represented in binary at some level, bitwise operators work on the binary values, not the values the binary represents.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal  The hash is hardly unique.  3^2^1 is 1^2^3 is 2^3^1 is 3^1^2 .  So there are 4 potential collisions.  However 3^2^1 is different from 3^2^2

Comment: Can you please explain me why 0001 ^ 0010 is resulting in 0011? You can also update your question...Thank you.

Comment: You're GREAT!! I realized the concept perfectly. BTW, an integral will always be 4 bits?

Comment: @YairNevet integers will typically be 32 or 64 bits depending on the operating system and language you're using. The maximum integer value you can represent with 4 bits is 15. I chose to use those low number because they only require a few bits. If you were to inspect the binary for those ints the values would be the same but with 28 more zeros on the left.

Comment: @YairNevet these two wikiepedia articles provide a lot of information about how integers are represented in hardware if you're interested; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_(computer_science) Also, if you're really interested in binary representations and bitwise operators you can probably find a CS class on ITunesU that just teaches those things.

Answer (score 4):

Elaborating a little bit, you see alot of `XOR`ing between fields in `getHashCode()` methods because its a safe way of getting an objects *signature*. The concept of a signature is that its like an object's fingerprint, and it needs to fit into 32 bits. This signature is used by a number of objects as a quick comparison, (though, if your planning on using it for that, take a look at that wikipedia article because you need to be careful about equality and hash-codes), or for some kind of addressing (as is the case with .net's `Dictionary` and Java's `HashMap`).

The obvious solution to me to get a Box's fingerprint is to simply add up the values, that way if any of them change you'll get a different fingerprint:
 `bx.Height + bx.Length + bx.Width`

Given that an equals operation might be really expensive (ie really slow), if we need to test the equality of two boxes:

- `Box {5, 10, 15}`
- `Box {30, 40, 50}`

Rather than do a full equals comparison, we can compare the two hash-code's, see that they're different, and skip the full equality comparison. In a dictionary this is critical to give us a fast method to find a *bin* (an element) to put the object in.

But if any of those values are too high, we could get an integer overflow exception, so instead of using addition, we use an XOR. Another solution, and one that's fairly unique to C#, is to use the `unchecked{ ... }` block, but using XOR is considered more elegant.

There is one more subtle thing we can do to increase performance, and you'll see this with alot of auto-generated hashcode methods (such as those produced by ReSharper or IntelliJ):
we can make the order matter by shifting (multiplying) each value.

```
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = x;
        result = 31 * result ^ y;
        result = 31 * result ^ z;
        return result;
    }
```

Now whats happening is that each field in your hashcode effectively has a place in the resulting 32 bits. What this means is that the two boxes:

- `Box {1, 20, 30}`
- `Box {1, 30, 20}`

would not have the same hash codes (they would have the same hash codes with your current system, but they're different!)

There's more than you ever wanted to know about hash-codes but I'll say one more thing.

*In both Java/Scala and the .net framework, if you overload either equals or hash-code, you **must** also overload the other*. You *must* also ensure that if two objects A and B have different hash-codes, then a call to A.Equals(B) **must** be false.